# Can one detect when a JFreeChart ChartPanel has changed its zoom?

Tags: java, jfreechart

In a JFreeChart application, is it possible for the application to detect when its ChartPanel object has changed its zoom state, i.e., it has either been zoomed in or zoomed out?  Is it possible to install a listener that will detect such a zoom state change?

For the record, I'm using the JFreeChart-FSE ("future state edition") library, so if there is no way to do this in the regular library, can it be done in FSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add a listener to the Plot of your ChartPanel.
The plot has the method addChangeListener().

So, when your plot is loaded, your compute the original zoom state.
You could associate the zoom state to visible data in your plot.
For example, the zoom state on domain Axis could be computed from the actual lowerBound and upperBound values like that :

```
    double lowerBound = yourChartPanel.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().getLowerBound();
    double upperBound = yourChartPanel.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().getUpperBound();
```

When your listener is called, you just have to check if the zoom state has changed since the last time.

Comment: @Moshe RubinAh, I have forgotten. If my answer addressed your need, please, accept it. 
It's an important point.

Comment: You are, of course, correct -- don't know how I missed that.  Thanks again!